# Tool to "write" within the pointer what lies around it (in order to mask things)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

There's a tool I believe that is used to erase particular elements in an image, where the pointer writes what is around it or something like that.

What is this tool and how to find it in Photoshop?

Comment: Hi drake035, maybe I am missing some but I do not understand your question as-is. Your title talks about writing, does that have anything to do with text? What do you mean erase? Are you trying to hide pixels by using a layer mask?

Comment: By "writing" I meant not text but clicking the mouse button with this tool active. I want to erase defects on an image, or hide them.

Comment: perhaps you should take a look at the Photoshop Basic Tools: http://www.photoshoplab.com/photoshop-tool-basics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds you like you want to use the **clone stamp tool (S)**. I would check out the Adobe help files - [Photoshop Help / 
Retouch and repair photos](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/retouching-repairing-images.html)

You can find this tool by pressing S.

Hold the Alt key and press the location you would like to copy from. You will have a brush tool that you can now start painting a copy from where you targeted.

You can also change the brush settings of the clone stamp tool by opening the brush panel.

There is also the **spot healing brush tool (J)**. This is just clicking over an area and copies from local spots. You have different options for how it copies (Content-Aware, Create Texture & Proximity Match).

Comment: I couldn't understand the question until I saw your answer, @AndrewH! Nice deciphering.